# A method for handing different data types

Tags: go

I want to make a method that accepts different data typs, but Go has no generics. I have to write the following duplicate code:

```golang
func GetRandomSubarrayInt64(candidates []int64, length int) []int64 {
    result := make([]int64, 0, length)
    if len(candidates) == 0 {
        return result
    }
    if len(candidates) <= length {
        return candidates
    }
    rand.Shuffle(len(candidates), func(i, j int) {
        candidates[i], candidates[j] = candidates[j], candidates[i]
    })
    return candidates[:length]
}


func GetRandomSubarrayString(candidates []string, length int) []string {
    result := make([]string, 0, length)
    if len(candidates) == 0 {
        return result
    }
    if len(candidates) <= length {
        return candidates
    }
    rand.Shuffle(len(candidates), func(i, j int) {
        candidates[i], candidates[j] = candidates[j], candidates[i]
    })
    return candidates[:length]
}
```

The code is almost repetitive.Is there a way to reduce duplicate code?

Comment: Better in what sense? What you have is readable, and should perform well. Those are probably the most important aspects of code. I can't think of anything better.

Comment: @Flimzy but code is almost repetitive.Is there a way to reduce duplicate code?

Comment: Not without hurting readability and performance. Duplicate code isn't always bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a interface that exports methods to swap items in a generic underlying array. Then you will need to implement this interface with your type-specific array/slice. Something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/2hNLAU1lo5L).

```
type ShuffleSlice interface {
    Swap(i, j int)
    Len() int
}

func GetRandomSubslice(candidates ShuffleSlice) ShuffleSlice {
    if candidates == nil || candidates.Len() == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    rand.Shuffle(candidates.Len(), func(i, j int) {
        candidates.Swap(i, j)
    })
    return candidates
}

type ShuffleSliceInt []int

func (s ShuffleSliceInt) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s ShuffleSliceInt) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
```

Comment: Best not to call a slice an array.

Comment: @Flimzy, yeah I know, but I wanted to be consistent with the example code in the question. Anyway, fixed in last edit.

Comment: It's better to correct an OP's improper terminology, than to propagate it :)